# Java: Date and offset issue?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a web application, and if the client side (in the UK which is in timezone UTC+0000)I send the date parameter as a string like so:

```
date = "2012-03-28 10:00:00 +0000" // this is meant to say "This is the date and time BST which is +0000 offset from UTC"
```

but when I receive this string in my Java REST service and try to parse it in to a date object using SimpleDateFormater it assumes that what im saying is: "this is 10:00 o'clock UTC and im located in a UTC+0000 timezone" so it stors it as 10:00 AM UTC time instead of 09:00 AM UTC time which is the correct conversation from 10:00 AM BST (which is +0000).

here is My sample java code:

```
String dateString = "2012-03-28 10:00:00 +0000";
Timestamp timestamp= null;
try{
DateFormat planningDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
Date date = planningDateFormat.parse(dateString);
timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
System.out.println("Time stamp value is: " + timestamp.getTime());
System.out.println("Date value after parse: " + date);
System.out.println("Time value passed in was: " + dateString);
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

which outputs:

```
$ java TimeTest 
Time stamp value is: 1332917100000
Date value after parse: Wed Mar 28 11:00:00 BST 2012
Time value passed in was: 2012-03-28 10:00:00 +0000
```

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 6):

> this is meant to say "This is the date and time BST which is +0000 offset from UTC"

That's your problem then. BST is one hour ahead of UTC. So 11am BST is 10am UTC, hence your output. You should probably read up a bit more on [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

The UK is *not* in "timezone UTC+0000" it's in "timezone Europe/London" which is UTC+0 in Winter and UTC+1 in Summer.

(As Bogdan says, time zones are hard and [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) is a much better date/time library than the built-in Java one *anyway*... but it would give you the same answer...)

EDIT: Just to make it perfectly clear, this value "2012-03-28 10:00:00 +0000" indicates 10am UTC in any sane system. That's 11am BST, just as Java is showing you. If you're trying to make it mean something else, you should stop doing that, as you'll be at odds with just about every system known to man.

Comment: Yes I know how UTC works, what im trying to say is I have the time in BST not in UTC. Im not sending it as UTC, Im sending it representing 10AM BST and want JAVA to convert my 10:00AM BST to 9:00AM UTC.

Comment: @Mo.: You appear *not* to know how UTC works, given that you've asserted *several times* in your post that the UK is on "UTC+0000" when we're *not*. BST is *not* +0000. The UK is *not* a UTC+0000 time zone. Time zone offsets give an offset from UTC, not from "standard time in whatever your time zone is".

Comment: What I meant by BST is that basically my time represents the UK time at the moment (10:00 AM my local time, not 10:00 AM UTC)

Comment: and if you are parsing a date in any language, for the UK you would have the offset to +0000, is that correct? Wether its in the summer or winter.

Comment: @Mo.: Then your value shouldn't use "+0000" as that's *not* the offset from UTC. We're *not* in a UTC+0000 time zone (which would be a fixed time zone which doesn't have any DST transitions). We're in the "Europe/London" time zone.

Comment: @Mo.: No, you wouldn't. You'd have the *actual offset from UTC*, either +0000 or +0100. I'm not sure how many more times I can say this... please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC

Comment: ok here is my problem:

I Have a date and time string from the browser(the user enters which he intends to represent the date and time where ever he is at the time) so if the user is in the UK and he enters a date and 10:00AM then he wants to pull back data for 10:00AM UK time (9:00AM UTC), how can I send this information over to the Java REST service to parse it correctly so it is stored as 09:00AM UTC and not as 10:00AM UTC?

From what I understand the only information I have in the client side is the local offset, so I pass that through using Javascript. (which is returning +0000)

Comment: Im sorry for dragging this on, I didn't mean to argue but I just think you were misunderstanding my question.

Comment: @Mo.: It sounds like your Javascript offset detection is broken. You should just call `Date.getTimeZoneOffset()` *on the appropriate date*. Are you calling `new Date(0).getTimeZoneOffset()` or something like that?

Comment: @Mo.: I don't think I misunderstood your question - I think your question demonstrated that you have or at least *had* a fundamental misunderstanding of what time zone offsets are meant to represent...

Comment: @Mo.: So, did you have any luck finding out what was wrong with your Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

TimeZone management is one the most challenging part when building a web application :). But there are several good projects on the web that offer good support for such cases. One of them would be Joda Time

> http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/